# Single photon's gravitational field: "where" is it?

Tags: gravity, photons

When a photon passes through a hole in a screen, the photon's energy is pretty localized, namely a the hole.

Now let the photon "fly" for a minute into the open void. The field representing (describing) the photon should have an excitation close to a half-sphere with a radius of around 18 million km.

If now the photon hits an object and makes a blip, its energy was deposited completely in this blip, so again we know quite well, where the energy "is".

But what about just before the blip: is it correct to say that the photon "is" just before the position of the blip with probability $\epsilon$/(area of half-sphere), where $\epsilon$ is our best description of the area within which the blip happens?

If this is so, what does that mean, just before the blip, for the gravitational field created by the photon's energy? Is its form also described only by some probability distribution?

Comment: Photons don't "fly". They are the results of local measurements that we do on quantum fields. "n photons at (x,y,z,t)" is logically equivalent to e.g. the quantum numbers of an atomic state. Those numbers are merely descriptions of an atom and not physical objects themselves and photons are also merely descriptions. If there were such a thing as quantum gravity (it's not clear that there is), then there would be an effective coupling of photons to gravitons, i.e. there would be a finite probability to not only find a photon in a field volume but also gravitons that are correlated with it.

Answer (score 0):

All the same issues you discuss also hold for massive particles such as electrons.

Except for something you bring up, such as energy localization, that simply isn't a real thing.

Energy in quantum mechanics belongs to states, not to places. And only some states have a definite energy, even then. For instance, in a hydrogen atom there is some energy based on the degree of freedoms of the coordinates for a center of mass and also some energy associated with the degree of freedom associated with a relative separation (and that degree of freedom is coupled to the potential energy of the system). It's not the case that the energy is associated with some fixed definite place.

And there is no rule that there be any localization at a slit. Or even at a far away surface. Imagine an entangled pair with each half of the particle pair hooked up to trigger a detector at a different location. Its possible to get interference, even very far away.

Now for gravity. Semiclassical gravity merely had the expectation value of the stress energy as a source term and there isn't a tested published fully quantum theory of gravity.

If quantum gravity were a statistical theory like regular quantum mechanics then it would merely predict the probability of various graviton modes and their mutual correlations with each other and with modes of other quantum field quanta such as photons, electrons and such. It would not have to have a detailed story about what was when where and exactly when something was created or destroyed (regular quantum mechanics doesn't have to do that). All it would need to do, as a statistical theory, is get the relative frequencies of the various experimental outcomes correct.

Sure, you might want a fun and easy to understand story too. But all a statistical theory *has* to do is make the statistical predictions correctly. And the predictions are merely about what you actually see through a completed interaction, not about what happened in between and when you weren't looking.